# How to stop Prettier from adding parentheses for one argument in an arrow function?

Tags: javascript, prettier

I'm using Prettier and the problem is that when I make an arrow function in JS like this:

```
arg => console.log(arg)
```

Prettier changes it to:

```
(arg) => console.log(arg)
```

I don't like this, how can I disable it?

Comment: https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#arrow-function-parentheses? (Also: Prettier's right.)

Comment: I know Prettier's right, but i think those parentheses are annoying.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the configuration settings in your .prettierrc file or prettier.config.js file.

for .prettierrc:

```
{
  "arrowParens": "avoid"
}
```

for prettier.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  arrowParens: "avoid"
};
```

Add these lines then all set, prettier no longer add parenthesis for arrow function.